# How to update dependencies in Gradle

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

Can any body can tell me how can I do something like `maven install -U` (update dependencies) in gradle.

I have problem I have added new dependency to my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

New dependency is:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
```

And during build or project synchronize my IntelliJ (version 14) is not even trying download this new dependency (I'm using gradle version 2.5)

In maven project IntelliJ had something like download maven dependencies. 
But for Gradle I don't see anything like this. This is like my project looks like

And can any body tell me why I don't see any *.jar on project list like maven does?

[image]

Comment: You can add `idea` plugin to gradle build script, with `apply plugin: 'idea'` and then after adding new dependency run `gradle idea`. It will download the dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using IntelliJ**

In the Gradle tool window, click refresh button. Here is the screen:

[image: Gradle tool window]

**Using terminal**

You must add to your `build.gradle` this line

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

And next if you are adding some dependencies and you want synchronize IntelliJ, you just use command

```
gradle idea
```

Comment: Great, thank You very much, that helps a lot, do You know how can i do this task from console/terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If any one have problem with finding Gradle Tool Window it's in:

View | Tool Windows | Gradle