# Flutter: update dependencies in build.gradle

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I keep dependencies in `pubscpec.yaml` updated with `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` but I never know how to update dependencies in `android/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
    }
```

and `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.4'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
}
```

Is there any command I could use to also update these dependencies?

I have to go to different pages like this one to find the latest versions and it's really difficult (and annoying) to find sometimes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Did you see this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33595105/11287483

Comment: I don't see Gradle option in View --> Tool Window